# Why do some websites not show a .php at the end of their file extension?

Tags: php, html, url

Sometimes when I look at a websites URL it will say something like this

www.website.com/index.php

and other times it will look like this

www.website.com/index/

Why does the second URL not have a .php or .html extension?

Comment: It's commonly called and implemented with "URL rewriting". Google for [`mod_rewrite`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/mod-rewrite/info) and `RewriteRule`s. Albeit in this case/example it might alternatively just be utilizing `MultiViews` and the `PATH_INFO`.

Comment: @mario why not post that as an answer? Would perfectly qualify if explained a bit more.

Comment: Using mod_rewrite, all incoming requests can be forwarded to a single PHP processing script, say an index.php, which then interprets the url path and query string, calls other scripts, and generates a dynamic response. Many frameworks work this way, so there's a single entry-point into the application, to enable initialization and configuration without duplicate code all over the place.

Comment: Thank you for the responses! I was able to find a great article that gets into detail about using mod_rewrite. I apologize for being ignorant on the subject and thanks Kufudo for the explanation.

Comment: Also, if anyone would like to make an answer for this I will gladly accept it so this topic can be solved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a normally configured web server,

```
www.website.com/index.php
```

tells it to load the index.php file from the webroot directory.  This

```
www.website.com/index/
```

tells it to look in the **/index/** directory for a file matching what is listed in the **DirectoryIndex** configuration directive in the server's **httpd.conf** file or in an **.htaccess** file in the web site's webroot directory (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex for details).

A sample configuration directive would look like this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html default.html default.htm
```

This would tell the web server to, when no filename is given, to look in the current directory for an **index.php** file, if not found look for an **index.html** file, and if not found a **default.html** file and so on for everything else on the line.

If you want to be able to run PHP files without having to have **.php** on the end of them, you would set a default handler in your configuration files (httpd.conf or .htaccess) such as:

```
ForceType application/x-httpd-php
```

This will tell Apache to handle all files as PHP whether they have a **.php** extension or not.  (See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#forcetype )

You can also use ModRewrite to remap the URLs if you prefer, but ModRewrite directives can be confusing and difficult to troubleshoot.